# Better way to remove extra space around the quote

Tags: spacing, quoting

There are extra spaces around the extensive (indented and long) quotations. My current solution to eliminate them is as follows:

```
\begin{quote}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
Lorem ipsum...
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{quote}
```

Is there any better handling for this issue?

My setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without packages, you can redefine `quote` to issue zero `\topsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\quote}{\list{}{\rightmargin=\leftmargin\topsep=0pt}\item\relax}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Maybe you want to set the topsep to another value.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The good solution is to use the [quoting-package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting).

```
\usepackage[noorphans,vskip=0.5ex]{quoting}
```

Change all your

```
\begin{quote}
[citation text]
\end{quote}
```

to

```
\begin{quoting}
[citation text]
\end{quoting}
```

I suggest you read the manual to learn the other useful options.

Comment: Thanks, but I found another workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Below lines worked for all quotes.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}} % before block quote
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}} % after block qoute
```

Comment: Not really the best idea.

Comment: @egreg But mustilica deserves honour for trying to find a solution.