# How to create a comment in Latex?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I am trying to create a comment like the following attached picture:

[image]

I am not sure how to achieve this in Latex. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? This is just a speech bubble  and some italic text.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I am not how to create such a speech bubble.

Comment: Just use a font that provides it. It's been in Unicode since 2014 (U+1F5E9).

Comment: @Ingmar like \char"1F5E9?

Comment: @Ingmar trying to figure out how to put  (U+1F5E9) in the latex.

Comment: The fontawesome5 package offers the \faComment command that results in a similar symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fontawesome5` package offers the `\faComment` command that results in a similar symbol to the one you show in your question. You could use it inside of a `quote` environment as the following MWE shows. If you want to use multiple similar comments, you could also define your own environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mycomment}{\begin{quote}\itshape\faComment\quad}{\end{quote}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[4-5]

\begin{quote}
  \itshape
  \faComment 
  \quad
  \lipsum[3]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[4-6]

\begin{mycomment}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{mycomment}

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

Apart from `\faComment`, `fontawesome5` also defines some other related symbols:

[image]

Comment: thank you. However, it takes creates space start of the comment and end of the comment. I wonder how to remove those space at the start of the comment and at the end of the comment.

Comment: Which space are you referring to? The vertical white space between the preceeding paragraph and the comment or the horizontal white space between the margin and the comment?

Comment: the vertical space between the preceeding paragraph and the comment. And the vertical space between the comment and the next paragraph.

Comment: Since the `comment` environment is based on `quote`, you can use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286517/134144).